# tableView is moving up more than the defined value

Tags: uitableview, uiscrollview, swift2

i have `TabBar` embedded  `tableViewController` and  in my Cell i have a `textView`  and am trying to move up tableView when  `textView's` editing begins this is how am doing this :

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {

 if textView == descriptionTextView {

    let indexPath: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 4, inSection: 0)
    self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Middle , animated: true)

    if textView.textColor == UIColor.lightGrayColor() {
        textView.text = nil
        textView.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
    }
}
```

its working fine but the scrolling is not smooth enough and its scrolling some points extra then coming  down maybe this is happening because of tabBars's frame

and for that i tried to set the content inSet :

```
tableView.contentInset = (UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: -30, right: 0))
```

but still having the same issue

see the value of `contentOffSet.y` from `ScrollViewDidScroll` when editing begins:

```
tableView is Moving : 236.5
tableView is Moving : 247.5
tableView is Moving : 254.0
tableView is Moving : 255.5
tableView is Moving : 190.0
tableView is Moving : 189.5
tableView is Moving : 189.0
tableView is Moving : 187.0
tableView is Moving : 185.0
tableView is Moving : 182.0
tableView is Moving : 178.5
tableView is Moving : 175.0
tableView is Moving : 171.0
tableView is Moving : 167.0
tableView is Moving : 163.0
tableView is Moving : 159.0
tableView is Moving : 155.0
tableView is Moving : 152.0
tableView is Moving : 149.0
tableView is Moving : 146.5
tableView is Moving : 144.5
tableView is Moving : 143.5
tableView is Moving : 143.0
```

above you can see that at first its going to `255.5` then coming down to `143.0`

anybody knows how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  func textViewShouldBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) -> Bool{

 if textView == descriptionTextView {

    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.frame.origin.y, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height - 190 )
    let indexPath: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 4, inSection: 0)
   UIScrollView .beginAnimations("UP", context: nil)
            UIScrollView .setAnimationDuration(0.3)
            scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, CGFloat(305
                + 70 * CGFloat(isiphone6())))
            UIScrollView .commitAnimations()

}
```

please try this

Comment: hey @KaranJeet thanks for responding ,  what is `isiphone6` here ?

Comment: don't use cgfloaft(305 + 70 * cgfloat(Tisiphone 6)).These are checks.Use only cgpointmake(0,300(moving up))